# Chrome Developer Tools: Make auto-complete case insensitive

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, case-insensitive

Is there a way to make auto-complete **Case Insensitive** in Google Chrome Console?

[image: DevTools auto-complete]

Answer (score 0):

No, this is simple auto-complete heuristics based on the characters. Showing available JS statements and previously input console commands as possible selections.